# How to configure log4j 1.2.7 for an application having multiple WAR files under Jboss/Wildfly?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j, wildfly

I want to configure log4j to get logs in a separate log file rather than the server.log file with having multiple WAR files in place. Let's say, I have two WAR files where war-A is the starting point (signup / login etc.) and then the war-B comes. Both are linked with each other. War-A is the general starting point for an EAP. log4j-A.xml of war-A has configurations to write logs into "ABC.logs" while log4j-B.xml of war-B has configurations to write logs into "XYZ.logs".

Now, the log4j is working but it is writing all the logs (of war-A and war-B) into the log file of war-A which is "ABC.logs". I want to switch to the configurations of war-B to write that logs into "XYZ.logs" as soon as have move from war-A (e.g. on next page after login).

I am using Wildfly 9.0.2 as my application server and it is initializing log4j from "C:\wildfly9.0.2\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\temp89993ff21\content-f176534\WEB-INF\classess\log4j-A.xml" every time.

Suppose, I have only access or can do changes in War-B because some other team is working on War-A (I can just deploy WAR-A and have that as starting point for my WAR-B), how can I achieve it to do logging in my desired file "XYZ.logs" as soon as my WAR application has started?

One more thing that I would like to mention is that if I build and deploy my WAR-B and then starts the application then the Wildfly picks log4j-B.xml as configuration file and do the right logging (but in this case, it writes the logs of WAR-A as well).

Comment: Log4j 1.2.17 stopped being maintained 7 years ago and version 1.2.7 is nearly 10 years old.  Are you sure you want to move forward with something this ancient?

Comment: Actually, I have a plan to update log4j version as well. That work is under progress as well. I will move on 2.12 or 2.17. Can you please suggest a way to handle the scenario that I mentioned above?

Comment: To clarify, you want all messages from WAR-A to log to their own file and all messages form WAR-B to log to a different file correct? Note this means even if WAR-B invokes a call to WAR-A the logs would go into WAR-A's log file.

Comment: Yes, I want to log each WAR messages in their separate log files as soon as have switch from one to another WAR file. Just for the understanding, assumes that WAR-B will not invokes any call to WAR-A.

Comment: If you simply include a `log4j.xml` in each deployment that should work then.

Comment: I have included it but it's not working as expected. Actually, I have multiple WAR files. WAR-A logs are working fine. Assume, I have two another WAR (B and C). I want these two WAR logs into a single log file which is not working correctly. Sometimes, few logs of WAR-B are writing into WAR-A which is wrong and sometimes WAR-B and WAR-C are not sync (out of order if we see the timestamp).